# Show item on hover and longer on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-hover

I want to be able to hover over a area and item 2 show up for X time when I hove (works fine with current code). But I also want it to show longer if it is clicked which does not work with my current code.

```
            <script>
            $("#redd").click(function() {

                     $("#raddress").show();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#raddress").fadeOut(2000);
                    }, 20000);
                });

            $("#redd").mouseenter(function() {
                     $("#raddress").show();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#raddress").fadeOut(5000);
                    }, 1000);
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason clicking it after the fact doesn't work is because the original fadeOut() function is still processing.

```
$("#redd").click(function() {

    /*
     * The following stops the animation, and fades in back in so that 
     * entire sequence resets, but with a longer time.
     */
    $("#raddress").stop().fadeIn();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#raddress").fadeOut(2000);
    }, 20000);
});

$("#redd").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#raddress").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#raddress").fadeOut(5000);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just included it into a little JSFiddle. I dont know witch JQuery you are using, but maybe that is the problem. 
Did I miss something? I hope it helps

HTML (Just 2 Containers) :

```
<div id=redd>Hover or Click me</div>
<div id=raddress>I am fading out</div>
```

JQuery (Given Code) :

```
$("#redd").click(function () {

    $("#raddress").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#raddress").fadeOut(2000);
    }, 20000);
});

$("#redd").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#raddress").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#raddress").fadeOut(5000);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Fiddle: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/wujood/zqobo0g0/1/)

Comment: I want it so that when you click it the time it stays last longer. Clicking has no effect with that code. The other answer worked. Sorry if I did not explain well i'm somewhat new to jQuery!